# sql join two tables and calculate average

Tags: join, ms-access-2010, average

This are my tables
table `BUSINESS`

`BUSINESSUSERNAME|BUSINESSPASSWORD|BUSINESSNAME|
 Res1            |123             |Cafe        |
 Res2            |456             |Foodtruck   |`

table `USER`

`USERNAME|USERPASSWORD|NAME|
 user1   |123         |mr.1|
 user2   |234         |mr.2|`

table `FOOD`

```
FOODID|FOODNAME|FOODPRICE|BUSINESSUSERNAME|
1     |CAKE    | 5       |Res1            |
2     |SHAKE   | 2       |Res2            |
3     |COLA    | 3       |Res1            |
```

table `FOOD_RATING`

```
FOODREVIEWID|FOODID|FOORATING|BUSINESSUSERNAME|USERNAME|
1           |2     |3        |Res2            |user1   |
2           |2     |5        |Res2            |user2   |
3           |1     |4        |Res1            |user1   |
4           |3     |1        |Res1            |user1   |
```

i would like to get this table
where BUSINESSUSERNAME = "Res1"

```
FOODNAME|FODPRICE|AVGRATING|
CAKE    |5       |4        |
COLA    |3       |1        |
```

Comment: pick one ( mysql, sqlserver, msaccess ). also why is businessusername stored in both food and food_rating - this should probably be remodelled

Answer (score 1):

**query**

```
select f.foodname, f.foodprice, avg(fr.foodrating)
from food_rating fr
inner join food f
on fr.foodid = f.foodid
group by f.foodname, f.foodprice
;
```

**output**

```
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
| FOODNAME | FOODPRICE | avg(fr.foodrating) |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
| CAKE     |         5 |                  4 |
| SHAKE    |         2 |                  4 |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/683477/5)**

Comment: i have this code but i cant get where to work
SELECT FOOD.FOODNAME,FOOD.FOODPRICE,ROUND(AVG(FOODRATING),1) AS FOODAVGRATING
FROM FOOD
LEFT JOIN FOOD_REVIEW ON FOOD.FOODID=FOOD_REVIEW.FOODID
GROUP BY FOOD.FOODNAME,FOOD.FOODPRICE
WHERE BUSINESSUSERNAME="something

Comment: well your missing the endquotes after `something`. however your structure is weird. why are you storing businessusername in both tables ?

Comment: I have 4 table which are BUSINESS,USER,FOOD,FOOD_REVIEW the BUSINESSUSERNAME is my primary key in table BUSINESS and im getting "Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'FOOD.FOODPRICE where BUSINESSUSERNAME = "something"

Comment: please edit this information back into the question ( and confirm which dbms your using ). also add the table structures for all tables involved

Comment: SELECT FOOD.FOODNAME,FOOD.FOODPRICE,ROUND(AVG(FOODRATING),1) AS FOODAVGRATING
FROM FOOD
LEFT JOIN FOOD_REVIEW ON FOOD.FOODID=FOOD_REVIEW.FOODID
WHERE FOOD.BUSINESSUSERNAME="LCpak"
GROUP BY FOOD.FOODNAME,FOOD.FOODPRICE

Comment: i got it i just misplaced the where statement where should go befor GROUP BY thank you amdixon so much

Comment: no problem - but i do think you should consider your table structure ( particularly the duplication of businessusername ) before you run into data problems

Comment: one last question if my food rating is null how do i turn it to zero

Comment: two options : 1. have an update statement like update food_rating set foodrating = 0 where foodrating is null or 2. in your select statement use coalesce(foodrating, 0). have a look at **[coalesce](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)**